# What does 초고수 mean?

Tags: meaning

A friend sent the following text:

> 네 ㅋㅋㅋ 곧, 한국어 초고수 되곘어요

I tried to look up `초고수`, but couldn't find it in the dictionary. What does it mean here? I assume it is somehow related to `고수`?

Comment: 초 means "extremely", or "super".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`초` is a korean prefix used to add a  meaning "super" or "extremely".

Its origin is a Chinese letter `超`, which means **transcending**.

It's often used to exaggerate.

So `초고수` can be translated to **super** 고수.

Examples:

> 초고효율적이다.  Super effective.
>
> 초인. A person that has abilities that transcends normal people.

But please do not confuse with:

> 초고추장

This `초` means vinegar(醋).

Comment: 초....고.... 추......장 ㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋ 너무 재미있네요.

Comment: @김성훈 네 **초**재미있죠.....ㅋㅋ

Comment: Please note that 초재미있다 is colloquial.

Answer (score 6):

고수 : outstanding person

초고수 : 어떤 분야나 집단에서 기술이나 능력이 극도로 뛰어난 사람.

At some area or group, extremely outstanding person in skill or competence

refer : http://dic.daum.net/word/view.do?wordid=kkw000836243&supid=kku010881220

> And I will enumerate places where we can hear the word 고수

1) Private institution : 고수의 비법, 영어의 고수 master's way, master of English

2) Go TV program

3) Game

4) Martial art cartoon book (or novel) : 검의 고수 sword master

5) Recently, it is frequently used in some housekeeping TV program.

Comment: 고수 is widely used in the gaming community, especially - so much so that it has essentially been adopted in English as a loanword :  [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gosu)